# nested routes in rails linking to wrong model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If my route looks like this

```
get 'users/:id/doc/:id', to: 'users/docs#show', as: :show_doc
```

and if my show controller action looks like this

```
def show
 user = User.find(params[:id]) #in this case it should be user id 6
 doc = Doc.find(params[:doc_id]) #in this case it should be doc id 29
end
```

and if the link in the index view looks like this

```
<% user.docs.each do |i| %>
 <%= link_to "#{i.id}", show_doc_path(user.id, i.id), target: :_blank %>
<% end %>
```

why does the link go to `localhost:3000/users/29/doc/29`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the route definition uses the same key (`id`) for both user id and document id. Use `doc_id` for document id and you should be good to go.

```rb
get 'users/:id/doc/:doc_id', to: 'users/docs#show', as: :show_doc
```